# localized routes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, localization, routes

In my RoR application, i want to be able to use custom routes depending on the local i am using.

Let's say i have a model `BookSale.  To access to the index method, i would like to have in the URL`/en/books-for-sale`instead of`/en/book_sales, and `/fr/livres-a-vendre` instead of `/fr/book_sales`.

What i have in routes.rb is the following:

```
localized do
  resources :books, only: [:index,:show]
end
```

And in my translations (and using I18n Dashboard) i have specified:

`routes.book_sales` `livres-a-vendre` for `fr` and `books-for-sale` for `en`, but it didn't work.

I have also specidied

`resources.book_sales` `livres-a-vendre` for `fr` and `books-for-sale` for `en` with no luck neither.

The routes that are working are still the traditional ones: `/fr/book_sales` and `/en/book_sales`

Anyone had similar experience and could suggest something ? Let me know if you need more info...

Thank you!

P.S: I am using the `gem route_translator`